# Displaying data with many to many relationship laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm the beginner of laravel 6. I just want to ask. I want to display data but it doesn't show.

**index.blade.php:**

```php
@if(isset($teachers))
  @foreach($teachers->qualifs as $qualif)
      <li>{{ $qualif->qual }}</li>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller:**

```php
public function index()
{
  $teachers= DB::table('teachers')->first();
  $qualifs = DB::table('qualifs')->find($teachers->id);
  return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers','qualifs'));
}
```

**qualif.php:**

```php
public function teachers()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('todolist\teacher', 'qualif_teachers');
}
```

**teacher.php:**

```php
public function qualifs()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('todolist\qualif', 'qualif_teachers'); 
}
```

Note: Data is storing correctly, only displaying issue.

> **ERROR**:Undefined property: stdClass::$qualifs

Comment: can you also post the whole classes of `teachers` and `qualifs` ? tables names, and local and foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

relationship belongs to a model instance that means to an eloquent object. when you are using query builder you will get stdObject instead of an eloquent object. and thus your relationship is not working. to make this work you have to use eloquent instead of query builder.

```
public function index()
{
    $teachers= teacher::get();
    return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers'));
}
```

and view will be like

```
@foreach($teachers as $teacher)
    @foreach($teacher->qualifs as $qualif)
        <li>{{ $qualif->qual }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: i added following in my code: $qualifs = Qualif::get();
$teachers1 = Teacher::get(); now error is :: Property [qualifs] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: as you are using `get()` for teachers you have to loop that first and then loop through the relationship.

Comment: can you please edit your answer with loop, i think that would solve my issue.

Comment: i added but i got list of qualifs table, it should show only 2 qualifications, it is showing qual table repeatedly.

Comment: do you write the code as same as my code?? i don't think so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201486/discussion-between-fayakon-and-zahid-hasan-emon).

Answer (score 0):

qualif its a collection, you can iterate or use the pluck method like

```
{{implode(', ', $teacher->qualifs->pluck('qual')->toArray())}}
```